# How to append some code and make it work with already loaded js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

A simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

```js
$('.test-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
$('.test-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).append('<a href="testing" class="test-link">Click here</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="test-form">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted it successfully creates the link with the class "test-link" which has a function ready to handle the click. When clicked I need to trigger the existing function, in this exemple it should alert "testing", but the link works as a regular link.

Comment: And since you're not binding the newly created element properly, the click event bubbles up the DOM and triggers the submit event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using jQuery's `.on()` method to ensure that your event logic is bound to elements that are added to the DOM in the future.

For example, you could change your code like this:

```js
$(function() {

$('.test-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).append('<a href="testing" class="test-link">Click here</a>');
});
  
$('body').on('click', '.test-link', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="test-form">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This means that your `click` handler will be called for any matching elements that currently exist, or that are added later on (ie after your form submit).

For more information, [see the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for `on()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I am actually using $(document).on('click', '.async-interface-link', function(e) @Heretic Monkey also pointed to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @FabioRizzoSciubba you're welcome - as a note, if the `.on()` can be called closer to `.test-link` (ie from `$('.test-form').on( .. )`) it is usually best practice and performs better - if this answer has helped in any way please consider accepting! :-)